# Проксирование запросов в Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть backend написанный на RubyOnRails и фронтенд на React (create-react-app). На фронте настроен прокси

```
"proxy": {
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://0.0.0.0:3000/",
    "ws": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "/"
    }
  }
},
```

Для запуска используется docker-compose

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  app-gems:
    driver: local

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
    volumes:
      - app-gems:/usr/local/bundle
      - ./api:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  web:
    build:
      context: ./web
    volumes:
      - ./web:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
    depends_on:
      - api
```

Когда запускается через `docker-compose up` то прокси не работает (просто не находит localhost:3000). Если запускать api на порту 3000, а фронтенд отдельно то все работает хорошо, почему так происходит?

Comment: потому что у вас физически два контейнера, у которых два разных айпишника и которые выглядят друг для друга как разные машины.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в web контейнере не запущен api,а вы пишите localhost... Нужно http://api:3000/

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Добавьте фрагмент кода. Объясните как исправить проблему.

Comment: Человек написал, что "просто не находит localhost:3000". Я сказал почему и как исправить. Вроде логично. Можно только добавить пояснение, что docker-compose прописывает в hosts соседей, чтобы на них ссылаться, а так все.

Comment: чем более развернутый ответ вы дадите, тем большему количеству людей он будет полезен. создание подобный ответов - цель это сайта.